# How to put delay for out going calls

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

Is there any option to put a delay to make a call in Android?

Once the user clicks the call button below method is called.

```
public class DialBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v("DileBroadCastReceiver","In onReceive()");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Log.v("DialBroadcast Receiver","Number is: "+number);
        }
    }
}
```

Then opponent user receiving call.

What I need is when user clicks the call button I should put delay for a second or two second, Is there any option to do like that.

I am a new developer. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     try {
            //set time in mili
            Thread.sleep(3000);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**or**

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //do something
                }
            }, 3000//time in milisecond 
);
```

Comment: Inside BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @MathaN yes U can use in Your BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @MathaN have U Try ?

Comment: Thanks :)  Working

Comment: @MathaN always Welcome Bro

Comment: I am having a  question May I ask? @Android Geeks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114702/discussion-between-android-geeks-and-mathan).

Comment: Can we call web service after getting response we should allow the call ?@Android Geeks

Comment: @MathaN yes U Can call Web when call recevied

Comment: Ok  Thank you :) @Android Geeks

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `onReceive` function

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.v("DialBroadcast Receiver","Number is: "+number);
        }
    }
}, 2000);    // 2000 for two seconds in milis
```